# Entity Framework 4: What is the best way to add and save an entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4

I have a BaseRepository class that is used by all repositories to save entities (new or updated):

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected void Add<T>(T source, CliCEntities context, bool isNew, EntityState state) where T : class
    {
        if (isNew)
        {
            context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(source);
        }
        else
        {
            if (state == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(source);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Save(MyEntities context)
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It's called like this:

```
public class MyEntityRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public void Add(MyEntity source, MyEntities context)
    {
        base.Add(source, context, source.ID == Guid.Empty, source.EntityState);
    }

    public void Save(MyEntities context) {
        base.Save(context);
    }
}
```

**The issue**

When the base.Save() is called, there's no difference to the data, EntityState is unchanged. I assume this is because the load was on a different Context instance, so the current Context doesn't know about any changes.

How can I change the above code so that my source instance has EntityState Modified (so that it would work)?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?  If you are you can set your DbContext as a singleton per request and it will be the same instance of the object every time.

Comment: I use UnitOfWork at Domain layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
protected void Add<T>(T source, CliCEntities context, bool isNew, EntityState state) where T : class
{
    if (isNew)
    {
        context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(source);
    }
    else
    {
        if (state == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(source);

            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(source, EntityState.Modified);
        }
    }
}
```

The big difference is this:

> context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(source, EntityState.Modified);

That way I can change the EntityState of the source object, so it's actually updated.

Comment: That's strange, I would have thought when you use AddObject is does this for you.  Remarks for `AddObject` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271(v=vs.100).aspx) says `Adds an object and its related objects to the ObjectContext and sets the entity objects to the Added state`

Comment: I'm confused about the method overall now.  Because you have an `Add` method, but you pass in an entity state, why?  Anything passed in to the Add method should surely just be set to `EntityState.Added` and never `EntityState.Modified`

Comment: Because of general complexity I need to implement an UoW pattern at Domain level which means I can't /won't be working on the same context instance. Which means I will be passing instances that are not attached to the new, current, context instance. So I need to check this. AddObject is fine, by the way, it's the else (update) bit that didn't work previously.

Comment: But surely you have an `Update` method for updating and an `Add` method for adding?  CRUD - Create, read, update and delete

Comment: Ah, you mean like that. It's the same method to reduce the number of access points, less that can go wrong and if it does you know where it's at. Maybe Add is a bit confusing yes, but it's what existed in the old code (can't economically change that).